# Html Helper with special htmlattributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Does anyone know how to pass html attributes like "data-date" to the Html.TextBox()??

It is used from the bootstrap datepicker.

Is there a way around it?

```
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DateFrom, new { @class = "small", type = "date", "data-date"="12-02-2012" })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use underscore instead of '-'.

So what you're after would go something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DateFrom, new { @class = "small", @type = "date", @data_date="12-02-2012" })
```

Comment: yea I understand that. The issue is that date-picker requires the field call "data-date", which is fine with HTML, but is not friendly with c# syntax. I think I have to change it back to the <input> for a work around. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "small" }, {"type", "date"} { "data-date", "12-02-2012" } }
```

instead of:

```
new { @class = "small", type = "date", "data-date"="12-02-2012" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add the date picker to the Html helper using bootstrap. [rudeovski ze bear's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917596/html-helper-with-special-htmlattributes#answer-9917634) made it easier.

This is how it worked for me.

```
@Html.TextBox("startdate", null
                 , new {@class = "type", @type = "date", @data_date="12-02-2012" })
```