# Is there a way I can customize what is generated by @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)`. This gives me:

```
<input data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="The User name field is required." 
       id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="xxx">
```

What I would like is for this to produce an `<input>` something like this:

```
<input class="login1" name="UserName" 
       placeholder="Username (or guest)" required size="25" type="text">
```

Is there a way I can customize the TextBoxFor to add placeholder, required and size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need validation related attributes, I think you have to use a `@Html.TextBox()`;

```
@Html.TextBox(Model.UserName.ToString(), Model.UserName, 
              new {@size ="25", @placeholder="Username (or guest)" ... })
```

`@` is used as a prefix to escape key words (such as @class). You may not need it for placeholder and size though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to add another parameter

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder="Username (or guest", ...}
```

See also: [Html Helper with special htmlattributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917596/html-helper-with-special-htmlattributes)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own helper:

```
public static class CustomHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomTexBoxFor<TModel, TProp>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProp>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", metadata.Model.ToString());
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("placeholder", "Username (or guest)");
        ... other attributes and htmlAttribute parameters

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove model validation to remove data-val-required attribute and add some html attributes like given below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName,new {placeholder="Username (or guest)", 
required = "required ",@size="25" })
```